# Full screen image gallery on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

On https://willhay.io/photography/, I've got a bunch of different pictures.

I want the user to be able to click on an image, then go into a sort of full screen image gallery with arrows going back and forth to switch between images and an X button to go back to the main photography page.

I have separate images on my server that are full resolution.

Would I just make the current images links that go to pages for each of the full screen/resolution images? I feel like there is a much easier way to do this. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ jquery colorbox

Comment: I'd prefer something more full screen and less like a popup if possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin ? This plugin lets you change between fullscreen and you can customize it into a slideshow and such too.

Comment: Not totally full screen, just takes up the width of height of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to do it the hard way I guess. Made separate html files for all 30 images... It was a huge pain but its finally done! Check it out here https://willhay.io/photography.

For the X button and the arrows, I used the unicode symbols and just copy and pasted them. The X button goes back to willhay.io/photography, and each arrow is a link and goes to the next image or the previous image's page. Let me know if you see any issues with it!